# ValueError: No axis named Column<rand() AS `CrossValidator`> for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to use pyspark.ml to execute classification.RandomForest using crossvalidation.

I have converted input file in CSV format to DataFrame format. When I execute the below code I'm getting the error as Value Error mentioned in the below error format.

Below is the python code.

```
import pyspark
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sql = SQLContext(sc)

trainingData= pd.read_csv("CSVfilepath", index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

print trainingData
numFolds = 10 


rf = RandomForestClassifier(numTrees=100, maxDepth=5, maxBins=5, labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", seed=42)
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator().setLabelCol("V5409").setPredictionCol("prediction").setMetricName("accuracy") 

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().build()

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[rf])
paramGrid=ParamGridBuilder().build()
crossval = CrossValidator(
    estimator=pipeline,
    estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
    evaluator=evaluator,
    numFolds=numFolds)

model = crossval.fit(trainingData)
```

The error obtained was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "randomforest_cv.py", line 46, in <module>
    model = crossval.fit(trainingData)
  File "/home/hadoopuser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 64, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "/home/hadoopuser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/ml/tuning.py", line 224, in _fit
    df = dataset.select("*", rand(seed).alias(randCol))
  File "/home/hadoopuser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2085, in select
    axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
  File "/home/hadoopuser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 353, in _get_axis_number
    .format(axis, type(self)))
ValueError: No axis named Column<rand(-4372709618522015412) AS `CrossValidator_42cab674dd6c1d100ef0_rand`> for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Could someone help me out in figuring the issue and how to solve it. I guess the problem is with DataFrame format.

Comment: You have created pandas dataframe .you have to create spark dataframe.